# Error Parsing Google Maps Data from XML using Apps Script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets, xml-parsing

I'm trying to extract the "formatted_address" from an XML that is created using a Google Maps API. I can't get past the XML part of the code. I'm getting the error "Exception: Bad request: http://0 (line 176)". Is there something I'm missing? How can I modifiy this? Any guidance is appreciated.
Line 176 is "var extractXml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(addUrl);"
The idea is to look up a "sloppy" address and return a Google standardized version in another cell in Google Sheets.
The snip is the XML as seen in browser when I paste in the URL. The "formatted_address" part is what I'm trying to return.[image: Google Sheet Snip]

```
   function addressFormat() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sss = ss.getSheetByName("format");
   var addr = sss.getRange(1,1,).getValue();
   var apiKey = "API Key Here";
   var  addUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" & addr & "&key=" & apiKey;
   var extractXml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(addUrl);
   var contentsXml = extractXml.getContentText;
   var xmlAdd = XmlService.parse(contentsXml);
   var response = xmlAdd.getRootElement();
   var records = response.getChild('GeocodeResponse');
   var recordList = records.getChild('result');
   var formattedAddd = recordList('formatted_address')

   return formattedAddd.getValue;

}
```

[image: Snip of XML]

Comment: Are you encoding the URL correctly?

Comment: Looking up info on the error. Something suggested improper encoding. I'm still not sure how to change or check what it is.

Comment: I think I see the issue now. It does get encoded in the search bar automatically when doing it manually by pasting into a browser. I probably need to convert it to a full URL in the actual Google sheet cell then use that instead of building it in Apps Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modification points:

- I thought that `var  addUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" & addr & "&key=" & apiKey;` should be `var addUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + encodeURIComponent(addr) + "&key=" + apiKey;` or `` var addUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=${encodeURIComponent(addr)}&key=${apiKey}`; ``.
- Please add `()` to `var contentsXml = extractXml.getContentText;`.
- From your script, I thought that you might want to retrieve the value of `formatted_address`. In this case, it is required to modify your script for retrieving the value from XML data.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function addressFormat() {
  var apiKey = "API Key Here"; // Please set your API key.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sss = ss.getSheetByName("format");
  var addr = sss.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  var addUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + encodeURIComponent(addr) + "&key=" + apiKey; // or var addUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=${encodeURIComponent(addr)}&key=${apiKey}`;
  var extractXml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(addUrl);
  var contentsXml = extractXml.getContentText();
  var xmlAdd = XmlService.parse(contentsXml);
  var root = xmlAdd.getRootElement();
  var ns = root.getNamespace();
  var formatted_address = root.getChild("result", ns).getChild("formatted_address", ns).getValue();
  return formatted_address;
}
```

#### Note:

- From your showing image, I guessed that your API key can be used for the API. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)

Comment: Thank you again Tanaike! This worked great. I modified the input as I wanted to just use it as a function in the spreadsheet. function addressFormat(input) Instead of the cell reference in the code. What did you mean about being careful with the API key?

Comment: @alanWall Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `What did you mean about being careful with the API key?`, when the API is not enabled, the API key cannot be used. So, I would like to have said about it. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: No problem! I appreciate the help. Take care Tanaike.